# How resolv this promise <pending> ? in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my first file : pro.js

```
const newly = async function getBalance(account,address){
    
    const resp = await fetch(
      `https://api-link`,
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'api-key': ....
        }
      }
    );
    
    account = await resp.json();
    return account;
  }

module.exports = {
    newly
}


second file : index.js

const myNewly = require('./pro');

app.post('/getBalance/type',jsonParser,function(req,res){

  
  console.log(myNewly.newly(account,req.body.address)); // return Promise { <pending> }
  
  res.send(myNewly.newly(account,req.body.address)); // return nothing in postman
  
})
```

Answer (score -3):

Either use `async`

```
app.post('/getBalance/type',jsonParser,async function(req,res){
  res.send(await myNewly.newly(account,req.body.address));
})
```

Or `then`

```
app.post('/getBalance/type',jsonParser,function(req,res){
  myNewly.newly(account,req.body.address).then(data => {
    res.send(data);
  }
})
```